# KQL Query to retrieve Subscription Name, Resource group name, and Tags sepparated into columns

Tags: kql, azure-resource-graph

I would like to retrieve all the resource group names with their corresponding tags and values to show them as a report, like this

[image]

I have tried queries to split the tags into columns without success.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve all the resource group names with their corresponding tags and values to show them as a report you can use `extend`, by using this `fields` can be taken which are present in tags, **CreatedBy** is a field stored in tags and name the field in the way to be viewed in the report. **createdBy** is name of the field this can be called by using `[tags].<field name in tags>`. So, the **Tags** can be separated into columns.

Below query is used to separate tags into columns:

```sql
resources 
| project 
  subscriptionId, 
  resourceGroup, 
  name, 
  type, 
  tags
| extend 
  createdBy = ['tags'].CreatedBy, 
  createdDate = ['tags'].CreatedDate, 
  owningTeam = ['tags'].OwningTeam, 
  reason = ['tags'].Reason
```

Output:

[image]